# file comparision using Awk in linux

Tags: regex, awk

I have two files 
File A.txt (Groupname; Groupid)

```
wheel:1
www:2
ftpshare:3
others:4
```

File B.txt (username:UserID:Groupid)

```
pi:1:1
useradmin:2:3
usertwo:3:3
trout:4:3
apachecri:5:2
guestthree:6:4
```

I need to create a output where it shows username:userID: Groupname like below

```
pi:1:wheel
useradmin:2:ftpshare
```

(and so on)

This needs to be done using awk for a unix class. After spending countless hrs trying to figure it out here is what I came up with.

```
awk -F ':' 'NR==FNR{ if ($2==[a-z]) a[$1] = $4;next} NF{ print $1, $2, $4}' fileA.txt fileB.txt
```

OR

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{ a[$2]=$2$1;next } NF{ print $1, $2 ((a[$2]==$2$3)?",ok":",nok") }' FileA.txt FileB.txt
```

can someone help me figure this out to get the right input and explain it to me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I am not trying to be nasty but it looks like you have no idea of what you are doing or the syntax of awk. Maybe looking here would help http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html

Comment: perfectly fine, thanks for the great site going over it at the moment ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1; next} $3 in a{print $1, $2, a[$3]}' a.txt b.txt
pi:1:wheel
useradmin:2:ftpshare
usertwo:3:ftpshare
trout:4:ftpshare
apachecri:5:www
guestthree:6:others
```

**How it works:**

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}` - Make input and output field separator as colon
- `FNR==NR` - Execute this block for `fileA` only
- `{a[$2]=$1; next}` - Create an associative array `a` with key as `$2` and value as `$1` and then skip to next record
- `$3 in a` - Execute this block for 2nd file if `$3` is found in array `a`
- `print $1, $2, a[$3]` Print field1, field2 and `a[field3]`

Comment: could also do `{$3=a[$3]}1`

Comment: Thanks @anubhava can explain FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1; next} and $3 in a{print $1, $2, a[$3]}

Comment: I've added a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you want to use `awk`, but you should also consider the standard tool designed for a task like this, namely `join`. Here is one way you could apply it:

```
join -o '2.1 2.2 1.1' -t: -1 2 -2 3 <(sort -t: -k2,2n fileA.txt) \
                                    <(sort -t: -k3,3n fileB.txt)
```

Because the input to `join` needs to be sorted on the join-field, this method leaves the output unordered, if this is important use [anubhava's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28693668/1331399) answer.

Output in this case:

```
pi:1:wheel
apachecri:5:www
trout:4:ftpshare
useradmin:2:ftpshare
usertwo:3:ftpshare
guestthree:6:others
```